# Crontab not working properly but log shows the opposite

Tags: python, web-scraping, cron, etl

im working on a small ETL that collects data using webscraping, cleans and manipulates it and sends to a local sqlite3 database.

If i execute the command /virtualenv_path/python /script_path/script.py it runs perfectly, but if i schedule this command with crontab it does not work.

It just does not send any data. However, my log file shows me that the crontab is executing script.py using my venv as expected.

So, what is going on? What should i do to solve this?

I suppose that my script is not incorrect because if i execute without crontab it works flawlessly and even with crontab it does not show any error (as i said, log file suggests that everything is going really well)

this is my repository: https://github.com/raposofrct/wescraping-ETL
there we have ETL folder that contains my script, crontab command that im using and my sqlite database.

thanks for any help or clue that you guys can give me.

Comment: Have you tried with another script in the same directory , to right a line to a file, to check your Cron entry?

Comment: "It just does not send any data"—what do you mean by "send" here? What user's crontab are you using, and does that user have write permission to the SQLite file? Have you checked for [local mail that cron would sent when errors occur](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207/12606)?

Comment: @Kendle, yes and it works pretty well.
I created a crontab command that created a folder and deleted it.

Comment: @Chris First, when i say 'not sending data' im saying that when i load my table it shows only the data that was already collected, so no data is being appended to the database table.

And about the crontab users, i did not specify any crontab user. I need to check this out deeper i suppose.

Comment: How did you configure the cron job?

Comment: @Chris i configured like this (would like to run at 6am and 6pm but i changed this sometimes to test every 15 min):                                                    


0 18,6 * * * /Users/nando/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/envs/dsaodevenv/bin/python /Users/nando/Comunidade\ DS/ds_ao_dev/ETL/script.py

Comment: @FernandoRaposo, okay, but where did you put that text?

Comment: @Chris using crontab-e on terminal
i inserted this command and left the crontab editor

Comment: Try to use an absolute path in create_engine('sqlite:///full/path/to/hm_db.sqlite',echo=False)

Comment: Okay, so that should be your user's crontab (though I'm not sure if it behaves differently on macOS).

Comment: @Roeften i tried this, but it couldn't connect, showed me an error

Comment: @Chris so what should i do now?

Comment: you need 4 slashes in the path like sqlite:////Users/nando/Comunidade DS/hm_db.sqlite if you simply edit the code. I had 3 in my comment by mistake. If that still doesn't work maybe it's a different issue.

Comment: @Roeften Seems the same solution as Chris gave me, right? i used 4 slashes when i tried, but im testing it again! you can see at my github the changes that i made on script.py

Comment: @FernandoRaposo essentially it's the same answer. Maybe the issue is the single quotes and the escaping remove the \ from  database_file or use double quotes or use the solution in chris's answer which is pretty flexible ;-)

Comment: @Roeften chris solution's worked really well! thank you for the support :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is likely working, but it's not putting data into the database file you're looking at. [`hm_db.sqlite` is relative to whatever the current working directory is](https://github.com/raposofrct/wescraping-ETL/blob/63a8b0007eb56aedfa99feaf6720dd151825ddf1/ETL/script.py#L496):

```py
DataBase(dados,create_engine('sqlite:///hm_db.sqlite',echo=False))
```

That is very unlikely to be the same directory you are in when you run the script manually. Either provide an absolute path or make the path relative to your script directory, e.g.

```py
from pathlib import Path


root_directory = Path(__file__).parent
database_file = root_directory / "hm_db.sqlite"

DataBase(dados, create_engine(f"sqlite:///{database_file}", echo=False))
```

Alternatively, log `os.getcwd()` in your existing script to figure out where your cronjob has been storing data.

Comment: Thank you so much chris! i was for like 6 hours thinking and searching about this issue!

Comment: The core problem is that your cronjob is running in some unknown directory. When your script opens `hm_db.sqlite`, it does it _in that directory_. The first time your cronjob ran, it created that file. And subsequent runs would have updated it. The option I show above with `pathlib.Path` essentially tells your script to open `path/to/script.py/../hm_db.sqlite` (1/2)

Comment: [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os%20getcwd#os.getcwd) returns the current working directory. That directory _should_ contain a second `hm_db.sqlite` that holds your missing data.

Comment: Do you know if i can make another crontab that adds, commits and pushes the changes to github automatically? my idea is to feed github every time that i collect more data.

Comment: @FernandoRaposo, you could, but tracking a binary blob of data in Git is a bit of an antipattern. I'm not totally clear on your use case so it might not be a big deal, but another option would be to insert the data into a cloud-hosted database somewhere. Then it would live outside of your repository.

Comment: thats fine.
Thank you very much